# Wiki-style app. Making keywords load alternate wiki pages

Tags: ios, objective-c, wiki

So I'm trying to create a wiki-style app and I'm confused on the setup.

For example, when I'm writing the wiki page for a certain item, there will be keywords on the page then when it clicked, should load another wiki page with that same keyword, and so on and so forth.

How would I be able to implement this into my app?

thanks in advance for anyone that helps!

Comment: Your question is vague but there are a few avenues to explore depending on the specifics of your problem. You can try using `UIWebViews` to encompass everything or if its just text you need you can use a custom component such as [`TTTAttributedLabel`](https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel) to have attributed labels with links inside them.

Comment: Well, I need to encompass basic test, headers, and pictures, like any basic wiki page. Would I simply use a UITextView or embed the text in a UIWebView? That `TTAttributedLabel` looks like something that would help me a lot.